# PHP function do not show rows if variable is not equal to 'yes'

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have created a PHP function that selects records from a database and displays them in a table:

```
function DashboardTickets($status, $colour, $header_text_colour, $text_colour) {
    global $pdo_conn;
    global $conn;

    global $usertype_user;
    global $usertype_admin;
    global $usertype_accounts;
    global $usertype_support;

    $stmt = $pdo_conn->prepare("SELECT * from tickets where deleted = :deleted and status = :status ");
    $stmt->execute(array(':deleted' => '', ':status' => $status));
    $records = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if(count($records) > 0) {
        //set the tickets_found to true
        $tickets_found=true;

        echo '<tr>
                <td colspan="8" bgcolor="#'.$colour.'"><strong><font color="#'.$header_text_colour.'">'.$status.' ('.count($records).')</font></strong></td>
            </tr>';
        $counter=0;
        foreach($records as $result) {
            $counter++;

            $stmt = $pdo_conn->prepare("SELECT * from ticket_updates where ticket_seq = :ticket_seq ");
            $stmt->execute(array(':ticket_seq' => $result["ticketnumber"]));
            $records = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $ticketupdates=count($records);

            if($result["locked_by"] != '') {
                $stmt = $pdo_conn->prepare("SELECT * from admin where sequence = :sequence ");
                $stmt->execute(array(':sequence' => $result["locked_by"]));
                $user = $stmt->fetch();

                $padlock = '<a href="/index.php?unlockticket='.$result["ticketnumber"].'"><img src="/includes/images/padlock_closed.png" width="25px" /></a><br>'.substr($user["forename"],0,1).' '.substr($user["surname"],0,1);
            } else {
                $padlock = '';
            }

            $stmt = $pdo_conn->prepare("SELECT * from admin where sequence = :sequence ");
            $stmt->execute(array(':sequence' => $result["assigned_to"]));
            $at_result = $stmt->fetch();

            echo '<tr class="notfirst" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="document.location=\'/helpdesk/reviewtickets.php?seq='.$result["ticketnumber"].'\'">
                    <td align="center">'.$padlock.'</td>
                    <td><font color="#'.$text_colour.'"><strong>'.$result["ticketnumber"].'</strong></font></td>
                    <td><font color="#'.$text_colour.'">'.ContactNameLookup($result["contact"], "Forename Surname").'<br><strong>'.CompanyNameLookup($result["company"]).'</strong></font></td>
                    <td width="400px"><font color="#'.$text_colour.'"><strong>'.stripslashes(strip_tags($result["subject"])).'</strong><br>'.stripslashes(strip_tags(substr($result["summary"],0,200))).'</font></td>
                    <td><font color="#'.$text_colour.'"><strong>'.$result["department"].'</strong></font></td>
                    <td><font color="#'.$text_colour.'">'.$result["opened_by"].'<br>'.$result["datetime"].'</font<</td>
                    <td><font color="#'.$text_colour.'">'.$result["last_updated_by"].'<br>'.$result["last_modified"].'</font></td>
                    <td><font color="#'.$text_colour.'">'.$at_result["forename"].' '.$at_result["surname"].'</font></td>
                  </tr>';
        }
    }
}
```

then when calling the function i do the following:

```
<?php DashboardTickets("Customer Reply", "F36F25", "FFFFFF", "000000") ?>
<?php DashboardTickets("Needs Action", "FF0000", "FFFFFF", "000000") ?>
<?php DashboardTickets("Open", "666666", "FFFFFF", "000000") ?>
```

i have permissions set in some variables

```
$usertype_user = $_SESSION["usertype_user"];
$usertype_admin = $_SESSION["usertype_admin"];
$usertype_accounts = $_SESSION["usertype_accounts"];
$usertype_support = $_SESSION["usertype_support"];
```

the above variables are either `'yes'` or `''`

i want to only show rows from the tickets table to certain users

for example, if `$usertype_accounts` is not equal to `'yes'` then DO NOT show rows from tickets `where department = 'Accounts'`

Comment: And where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: i don't know how to stop the query running (where department = 'Accounts') if the $usertype_accounts variable is not = 'yes'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways you can handle this.

1) Add a condition in your tickets result loop, that skips a record when the value of `$usertype_accounts` is not 'yes' and the record's department is 'Accounts'.

```
foreach($records as $result) {
    if ($usertype_accounts != 'yes' && $result['department'] == 'Accounts') {
        continue; // skip to the next result
    }
    //...
```

2) Alternatively (and this is the better solution), you could make your query dynamic, so that certain conditions are added based on the values of your permissions variables.  For example:

```
$baseSql = "SELECT * from tickets where deleted = :deleted and status = :status";
// Do something like this for all your permission variables
if ($usertype_accounts != 'yes') {
    $baseSql .= " and department != 'Accounts'";
}
$pdo_conn->prepare($baseSql);
//...
```